# Most optimized way to split a string change a piece of it across an array

Tags: javascript

I have some data coming in from an API, where for mobile devices I must change a number inside a string, to render out proper images.

The data looks like this:

```
http://akimages.shoppe.com/dyn_rppi/650.0.85.0/Store/large/140921_p06mw2_CT_hbqz7.jpg
http://akimages.shoppe.com/dyn_rppi/650.0.85.0/Store/large/1556_q0622_HZ_avez2.jpg
```

There will always be a `650.0.85.0` inside the string.  I need to target the `650` directly and change them all to `380`

What is the most optimized way to filter through all these strings and exchange `650` for `380`?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with going through each element of the array and using `.replace("650.0.85.0","380.0.85.0");` I may be misunderstanding the question, but iterate and replace is pretty optimized, I think?

Comment: i honestly didnt know replace was a function could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaScript Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Iterate through your array of Strings, and for each one, you can call:

```
myStr.replace("650.0.85.0","380.0.85.0");
```

As long as the subStr is unique across all, I don't believe using the entirety as a search term is inappropriate, whereas searching for "650" alone would be riskier in this case.

Comment: I'mma leave this open for a bit longer but I'mma implement.  if no other critiques come about i'll mark correct in 30.